# pandas - return column of exponential values

Tags: python, pandas

Starting from a sample dataframe `df` like:

```
a,b
0,0.71
1,0.75
2,0.80
3,0.90
```

I would add a new column with exponential values of column `b`. So far I tried:

```
df['exp'] = math.exp(df['b'])
```

but this method returns:

```
"cannot convert the series to {0}".format(str(converter)"
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <type 'float'>
```

Is there a way to apply a `math` function to a whole column?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Well `math.exp` doesn't understand `Series` datatype, use numpy [`np.exp`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.exp.html) which does and is vectorised so operates on the entire column:

```
In [24]:
df['exp'] = np.exp(df['b'])
df

Out[24]:
   a     b       exp
0  0  0.71  2.033991
1  1  0.75  2.117000
2  2  0.80  2.225541
3  3  0.90  2.459603
```

Comment: @Confounded post a new question with raw data, code to reproduce your df, your attempts, full error traces, desired result. answering questions in comments is counter-productive

Comment: I tried it but it returns "TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type float which has no callable exp method"

Answer (score 0):

try using:

```
df['exp'] = df.b.apply(np.exp)
```

Comment: This does work although it is slightly less direct than just calling np.exp with Series as a parameter and may perform slightly differently. I disassembled the two variants and there is an extra attribute lookup for the apply method, which might account for this difference:

>>> timeit.timeit("e = np.exp(x)",setup="import pandas as pd; import numpy as np; x = pd.Series(np.linspace(-10, 10, 2001))")
110.47226533893357

>>> timeit.timeit("e = x.apply(np.exp)",setup="import pandas as pd; import numpy as np; x = pd.Series(np.linspace(-10, 10, 2001))")
111.62233564382561